# How to run R program

Tags: r

I am new to R. I install R cmd in Windows an trying to run this program:
https://github.com/jsugarelli/xml2relational

I successfully run
`install.packages("xml2relational", dependencies = TRUE)` as per the docs to install the dependencies

However, I cannot get `library(xml2relational)` to work

I run it but nothing happens. No file generated and no output.

I also try run `xml2relational.r` in cmd but it's return object not found

Am I doing anything wrong or missing some command?

Comment: `library(xml2relational)` just loads the package, it doesn’t “run” anything and isn’t expected to produce any output. It just allows you to use functions from the package. You would need to then call functions to do whatever you’re trying to do, e.g., [example from the readme](https://github.com/jsugarelli/xml2relational).

Comment: After `library(xml2relational)` (which typically prints nothing or just "hello world" messages), then type in `source("path/to/xml2relational.r")`. You might need to know where R is running, use `getwd()` to see its current working directory, optionally change it with `setwd("path/to")`, after which you are better informed how to frame your `source(.)` call. Good luck! Welcome to R!